# Why does jquery internet explorer and opera throw undefined jquery($) error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, document-ready

I have a script running file while in chrome and safari, but when i try testing it on Internet explorer and Opera i get an undefined error when using '$'.

```
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http:////ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    });
 </script>
 </head>
```

Can someone figure out what's wrong with this? I guess it's something to do with the way IE and Opera do things in the background but i have no idea how to go about fixing this.

I've tried moving where i define jquery but nothing. Tried moving all the js to the bottom of the doc as well but nothing.

The script has a lot more code to it for button presses and blur methods but that would take up a lot of space and seeing as teh script falls over on the document ready method i thought it would be a waste but if you feel it should be there please let me know.

Comment: `language="JavaScript"`? This is 2013. Don't write HTML 3.2.

Comment: @Quentin: Darn, does that mean I should ask my `VBScript` questions elsewhere? ;-)

Comment: that's a good point @Quentin, must have copied that from an old file or something. Thanks for the spot.

Answer (score 5):

The only thing odd about your code is the URL.

```
http:////ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js
```

should be

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js
```

or (so you can freely switch between HTTP and HTTPS):

```
//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js
```

If that isn't the issue, then it must be in some code you aren't sharing with us.

Comment: Should be noted that if you're developing [on windows] locally (e.g. the page you're working on begins with `file:///`) you _must_ supply the protocol (`http://` over `//`).

Comment: Good point, although `file:///` causes enough problems that I'd strongly advise running a local webserver instead.

Comment: I'm running a local server. I was thinking about the URL 'http:////' the other day in fact and forgot to check if it made any difference. Seems to have done the job, thanks for the help.